# A problem in conditional expectations

Tags: conditional-expectation

Is there an example of *dependent* random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that
$${\bf E}(X|Y)=0\ \mbox{ and }\ {\bf E}(Y|X)=0\ \mbox{ almost surely?}
$$

Comment: Randomly pick a variance. Then let X and Y be normal random variables with 0 mean and the variance you picked. They will not carry information about means of each other but they will be dependent. This dependency can be discovered by analyzing their squares for example.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc If we take $X=Y$ then ${\bf E}(X|Y)=Y$ which is not zero a.s.

Comment: Why are you taking X=Y? That's another dependency. Randomly generate a positive number p. Then randomly generate X~N(0,p) and Y~N(0,p) and observe the samples. You need to regenerate p everytime as well.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc Let us reformulate your answer. Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be independent standard normal random variables. Then ${\bf E}(\alpha\beta|\alpha\gamma)=0$. Could you explain, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:
\begin{equation}
p(x,y) = \frac{2}{\pi\, 
   \left(x^2+y^2+2\right)^2} .
\end{equation}
This a a bivariate Student-t distribution with 2 degrees of freedom, location vector $(0,0)$, scale matrix $I_2$. The marginal distributions are
\begin{align}
p(x) &= \int p(x,y)\,dy = \frac{1}{\left(x^2+2\right)^{3/2}} \\
p(y) &= \int p(x,y)\,dx = \frac{1}{\left(y^2+2\right)^{3/2}} .
\end{align}
As required, $x$ and $y$ are not independent because $p(x,y) \ne p(x)\,p(y)$.
The conditional distributions are
\begin{equation}
p(x|y) = \frac{p(x,y)}{p(y)} 
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
p(y|x) = \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)} .
\end{equation}
As required, the conditional expectations are
\begin{equation}
E[x|y] = \int x\,p(x|y)\,dx = 0
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
E[y|x] = \int y\,p(y|x)\,dy = 0 . 
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have got your idea. It is sufficient that the joint density be symmetric with respect to $x$-axis and to $y$-axis.